# how can we define dynamic(in parabola curve) Path of ViewObject(Bitmap)

Tags: android, canvas, view, 2d

I am Currently working on One **2D Android Game**,

In this game One **ViewObject(Bitmap)** is moving Across Screen On **Parabola Path** Like in this   Image,  But this Path is Static, the Static path is getting throught the Drawing with Fingure on canvas,

As Same as signature Drawing.

[image]

The Bitmap Move code On this Static Path is

```
//animation step
private static int iMaxAnimationStep = 900;
private int iCurStep = 0;
private Path ptCurve = new Path(); //curve
private PathMeasure pm;            //curve measure
private float fSegmentLen;         //curve segment length


 //init smooth curve
    PointF point = aPoints.get(0);
    ptCurve.moveTo(point.x, point.y);

    for(int i = 0; i < aPoints.size() - 1; i++){
        point = aPoints.get(i);
        PointF next = aPoints.get(i+1);
  ptCurve.quadTo(point.x, point.y, (next.x + point.x) / 2, (point.y + next.y) / 2);
    }

    pm = new PathMeasure(ptCurve, false);
    fSegmentLen = pm.getLength() / iMaxAnimationStep;//20 animation steps

    //animate the Bitmap
    Matrix  mxTransform = new Matrix();
    if (iCurStep <= iMaxAnimationStep) 
    {          

        pm.getMatrix(fSegmentLen * iCurStep, mxTransform,
                PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG);
        mxTransform.preTranslate(-Bitmap.getWidth(), -Bitmap.getHeight());


       canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, mxTransform, null);

        iCurStep++; //advance to the next step
        mPauseViewHandler.post(mPauseViewRunnable);
    } else {
        iCurStep = 0;

    }
```

But My Problem is I want to Move This **ViewObject(Bitmap)** On **Dynamic Path(in parabola curve)** 
& that Dynamic curved path will work in Any Device.

I have searched Lot but i can't Find Solution How to get **Dynamic Path (in parabola curve)**.

help! If you have  Any Solution,Suggestion, idea ,tutorial regarding this post is Mostly Appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple enough to fill `aPoints` array based on your screen size, and get a parabolic path based on those points. I've removed all your bitmap/animation code, this code below will calculate the path and draw it on the screen.

We need a new variable to set how many curves we want in the screen. If you prefer it's easy to change the math and define the size of the curve instead.

```
private int numberOfCurves = 5;
```

With that it's simple to calculate 3 points for each parabola:

```
public void calculatePoints(){
        float w = v.getWidth(); //Screen width
        float h = v.getHeight(); //Screen height
        float curveSize = w/numberOfCurves; // Curve size
        float curveHeight = (h/100) * 20; //80% of the screen size
        Log.d(TAG,"h:"+h +" - w:" + w); 
        float lastX = 0; //last used X coordinate
        for (int i=0;i<numberOfCurves;i++){  //for each curve we'll need 3 points
            float newX = lastX + curveSize; 
            PointF p = new PointF(lastX, h); //first point is the last point                
            PointF p1 = new PointF((lastX + newX)/2, curveHeight); //the middle point is halfway between the last and the new point
            PointF p2 = new PointF(newX,h); // the new point is last point + the size of our curve
            aPoints.add(p);  //fill in the array 
            aPoints.add(p1);
            aPoints.add(p2);
            lastX = newX; //update last point
        }

            //log our points
        for (PointF p : aPoints){
            Log.d(TAG,p.x +"-"+p.y);                
        }
    }
```

Now we have a set of points defining each parabola, we need to draw it. Instead of using quadTo, use [cubicTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#cubicTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29). It takes 3 points and draws a curve connecting them. Put it onDraw, and you have your parabolas drawn on the screen.

```
private Path ptCurve = new Path(); //curve
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            calculatePoints();

            Log.d(TAG,"DRAWING");
            PointF point = aPoints.get(0);
            ptCurve.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
            for(int i = 0; i < aPoints.size() - 1; i+=3){
                point = aPoints.get(i);
                PointF middle = aPoints.get(i+1);
                PointF next = aPoints.get(i+2);
                ptCurve.cubicTo(point.x, point.y, middle.x,middle.y, next.x , next.y);
            }

                canvas.drawPath(ptCurve, paint);            
        }
```

So your `ptCurve` variable is now filled with a parabolic path, with as many curves as you've defined earlier, and it will work on any screen size.